# Zend-F2: How to configure "Mysqli: The ext/mysqli driver"

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I am using ZF v2.2. I am having a problem during database connectivity with "Mysqli: The ext/mysqli driver". Actually i am unable to figure out the process of "connecting to database & then using $sql->select(),  $sql->update() etc".

Any idea how to configure this?

> **File: autoload/db.local.php**

```
return array( 
   'db' => array(
      'driver' => 'Mysqli', 
      'username' => 'root', 
      'password' => 'redhat', 
      'database' => 'mydb', 
      'host' => 'localhost' 
    ), 
    'service_manager' => array( 
      'factories' => array( 
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory', 
         ),
      'aliases' => array( 
         'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter', 
       ),  
    ),
);


public function indexAction() { 
   $db=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('db'); ` `echo $db->getDriver()->getConnection()->isConnected(); 
//**returns false**. 
}
```

Comment: showing us exactly what you do would be a nice first step. As DB configuration is explained within the official documentation fairly well.

Comment: **File: autoload/db.local.php**

return array(
'db' => array(
'driver' => 'Mysqli',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'redhat',
'database' => 'mydb',
'host' => 'localhost'
),
'service_manager' => array(
'factories' => array(
'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
),
'aliases' => array(
'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
),
),

);

**error**
public function indexAction()
{
$db=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');

`        `echo $db->getDriver()->getConnection()->isConnected(); //**returns false**.

}

Comment: do you really have the index action within your config file?

Comment: @cptnk: indexAction() is in my album controller.